# Is there a way to boot to the fastboot mode?

Tags: fastboot, amazon-kindle-fire

I booted to the TWRP recovery for the first tiem and played with it by wipping everything using all the wipe options. Then I ended up unable to boot to the fastboot mode, normal mode or recovery mode.

And here is the message I got:

```
exec '/system/bin/sh' failed: No such file or directory
```

I read that I only have two options to boot to the fastboot mode:
1- Factory cable.
2- Opening the case and using the motherboard.

Is there a new way other than these last options?

Comment: If you have one of the custom bootloaders then you don't need either of those methods to get into fastboot; it will automatically listen for fastboot commands for 5 seconds at the beginning of the boot sequence. How did you install TWRP?

Comment: I used Kindle Fire Utility from XDA Devs.